# I have to create a code that changes the accounting symbol at the front to a different version?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code which changes the currency symbol automatically throughout the workbook, however looping through each sheet in the workbook is a long procedure which takes too long.

Please tell me how to make it run faster but have it still operate as it is meant to? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub curren()

    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim strFormat As String
    Dim fin As String

    Dim initialMode As Long

    initialMode = Application.Calculation 'save calculation mode
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    If Sheets("Summary").Range("e35").NumberFormat = "_-[$$-409]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-409]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-409]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ " Then
        fin = "_-[$$-409]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-409]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-409]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "

    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e35").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" Then
        fin = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e35").NumberFormat = "_-[$£-452]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-452]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-452]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
        fin = "_-[$£-452]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-452]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-452]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"

    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e35").NumberFormat = "_-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$€-2] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
        fin = "_-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$€-2] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"

    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e35").NumberFormat = "_-[$AED] * #,##0.00_-;-[$AED] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$AED] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
        fin = "_-[$AED] * #,##0.00_-;-[$AED] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$AED] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"

    End If

    Select Case Sheets("Input").Range("e12")
        Case "Dollar"
            strFormat = "_-[$$-409]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-409]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-409]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
        Case "Rand"
            strFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        Case "Pound"
            strFormat = "_-[$£-452]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-452]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-452]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
        Case "Euro"
            strFormat = "_-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$€-2] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
        Case "Dirham"
            strFormat = "_-[$AED] * #,##0.00_-;-[$AED] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$AED] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    End Select

    Dim x As Boolean

    For Each s In Application.Worksheets
            s.Activate
            x = False
            If s.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
                s.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                x = True
            End If
            Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = fin
            Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = strFormat
            s.Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
                xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
            If x = True Then
                s.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
    Next s
    Application.Calculation = initialMode
End Sub
```

I looked at a bunch of threads and so far I managed to speed it up but my code is less versatile and less adaptable to change.

I had a code which used a similar method which was lightning but it required the within function for find&select to be set to workbook, which to my knowledge is not possible.

Comment: If you want to apply this code to different worksheets in the workbook you will need to loop (through the worksheets). You cannot edit different worksheets in one step. So I guess besides disabeling `.ScreenUpdating` and setting `.Calculation` to manual, there is not much space to improve the speed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Is there a way to search those formats and then change them for the entire workbook without specifying the ranges?